# getting wrong result in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get result of each date using SP & I am using loop and appending sql statements using union all but it is picking up last value of variable date.

**Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE `bugs` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `severity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**SP :**

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS search$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE search(startDate DATE, endDate DATE)
     BEGIN
         DECLARE result  VARCHAR(255);
         SET @iterDate = DATE(startDate);
         SET @result = '';
         label1: LOOP
            SET @result = CONCAT(@result, ' SELECT DATE(@iterDate), count(*) FROM bugs WHERE open_date = DATE(@iterDate) AND close_date > DATE(@iterDate) UNION ALL');
            SET @iterDate = DATE_ADD(@iterDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
            IF @iterDate <= DATE(endDate) THEN
                ITERATE label1;
            END IF;
            LEAVE label1;
         END LOOP label1;
         SET @result = LEFT(@result, LENGTH(@result)-LENGTH('UNION ALL'));
         PREPARE stmt FROM @result;
         EXECUTE stmt;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This will take date range and record count on each date. In mine it is taking last date (endDate+1) for executing last formed query.

Comment: Instead of a procedure i'd use a calendar table and a LEFT JOIN to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of @iterDate incrementing (SET command) and @iterDate condition check (IF command).

Comment: This will make loop infinite.

Comment: dont have access to try it right now but you could just add the incrementor within the IF block just before iterating.. wont it work?

Comment: Yes but it is updating value  at last not while appending so it is taking endate+1. Did u get it what is wrong here?